# Looping through and comparing values in different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I have two dataframes:

df1:

| Lower | Upper | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 7 | first |
| 8 | 14 | second |
| 15 | 23 | third |

df2:

| Score |
| --- |
| 5 |
| 3 |
| 8 |
| 13 |
| 20 |

I want a third result dataframe df3 such that if the score in df2 is between the lower and upper values of df1, that row gets assigned the corresponding rank from df1

| Score | Rank |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | first |
| 3 | first |
| 8 | second |
| 13 | second |
| 20 | third |

Comment: Check [pandas.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A faster option is to use `pd.cut` as suggested by @psidom:

```py
# create an intervalIndex, luckily your data does not have overlaps
intervals = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df1.Lower, df1.Upper, closed="both")
# map intervals to `Rank` column
mapping = pd.Series(df1.Rank.array, index=intervals)
# compute new column:
outcome =  pd.cut(df2.Score, bins=intervals).map(mapping)
df2.assign(Rank = outcome)

   Score    Rank
0      5   first
1      3   first
2      8  second
3     13  second
4     20   third
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame( [[0,7,'first'],[8,14,'second'],[15,23,'third']], columns = ['Lower', 'Upper', 'Rank'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame( [5,3,8,13,20], columns = ['Score'])

result = []
for index, val in df2.iterrows():
    for id, rank in df1.iterrows():
        if val['Score'] >= rank['Lower'] and val['Score'] <= rank['Upper']:
            result.append(rank['Rank'])
            break

df_result = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Score','Rank'])
df_result['Score'] = df2['Score']
df_result['Rank'] = result
```